# Limit of multivariable function 3

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I wonder what is the answer of this limit, because the course assignment views my answer as wrong:

> $$\lim_{\substack{x\to0 \\y\to0}}  \frac{(x^2)(y^2)} {(x^2)(y^2)+(x-y)^2} $$ [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGGqY.png) please see the
>   pic for clear view

1. I did substitution $x=r\cos{\phi} $and $y=r\sin{\phi}$ and it turns the
   given limit to 0
2. I set $x=0$ as $y \to0 $and I got limit=0
3. I set $y=0$ as
   $  x\to0 $and I got limit=0
4. I set $y=mx $ as $ x \to0 $and I got limit=0

But the result does not show the answer and tells that $$\lim=0$$ is the wrong answer. Can you elaborate on this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}.$$If $x=0$, then $f(x,y)=0$, and if $x=y$, then $f(x,y)=1$. Therefore, $f$ has no limit at $(0,0)$.

Comment: if $x=y$ then we have $f(x,x)=f(y,y)$ and if $x=0$ then we get $f(0,y)$

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can choose $2$ curves that result in different limits. The first one is $y = x$, and the limit is $1$. The second is $y = \dfrac{x}{x+1}\implies xy = x-y$ , and the limit is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus there is no limit at $(0,0)$.